# Extracting single String/Int from fetched API data list

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am struggling to extract single values (strings and Int) from the data I fetched from an API. I fetch the data in the form of a list:

```
class apiCall {
    func getRockets(completion:@escaping ([Rockets]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let rockets = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Rockets].self, from: data!)
            print(rockets)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(rockets)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Then when I try using it in a View I succeed when using a List to view the values, like it shows the list of the names from the API data. But then when I want to view a single value like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RocketStatistics: View {
    
    @State var rockets: [Rockets] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(rockets[1].name)
        }
        .onAppear {
            apiCall().getRockets { (rockets) in
                self.rockets = rockets
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
struct RocketStatistics_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RocketStatistics()
    }
}
```

It does not even give me an error, but my preview just won't update and keeps crashing.
So my question is how can I extract single values from this API data in List form and use these single values in my whole project?

To keep it simple and make it work first I started just with fetching the "name" from the API:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Rockets: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name : String
    
}
```

When it all works I would also want to use Integer values from the API in my project, so tips on how to that are also welcome!

Comment: Try this code ```VStack{
    if !rockets.isEmpty {
        Text(rockets[1].name)
    }
}
``` Since at the starting and at the time of API calls, your array is empty. so  rockets[1] bounds the array..

Comment: @RajaKishan If there is only **one** item in the array `rockets[1]` will still crash.

Comment: If have only one item then pass 0 ```rockets[0]```. array start with zero index.

Comment: Did you mean `List(rockets) { rocket in Text(rocket.name) }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever get items by a hard-coded index in a SwiftUI view without any check. When the view is rendered the first time the array is empty and **any** index subscription will crash.

Always check if the array contains the required number of items. In this case the array must contain at least two items

```
VStack{
    Text(rockets.count > 1 ? rockets[1].name : "")
}
```